# Is that possible to have multiple external ips on the same Windows Server 2012 r2 and bind different external ip to each website

Tags: asp.net, iis, ip, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have currently 24 ips allocated to my dedicated server

I am able to use them on virtual machines such as HYPER V setups

But i wonder something else

Lets say i have 3 different asp.net .net 4.5 IIS websites on the windows server 2012 R2

I want to assign each one of these websites to different ips (public static ip addresses)

Is this possible ?

For example

www.example.com will point to 198.245.73.83

www.monstermmorpg.com will point to 198.245.73.82

But both will be on same windows server installation without using virtual machine

Can i achieve this without virtual servers and without having more than 1 physical network card on windows server 2012 R2, IIS , asp.net .net 4.5 websites combination

Ty very much for answers

Why i don't want to build virtual servers ?

Because it seriously impacts performance, costs etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Assuming you have bare metal access to your Windows Server (and it's likely you do if you have a *dedicated server*), you can bind multiple IP address to your (single) network card (Control Panel -> Network):

[image: Advanced TCP/IP Settings]

In IIS Manager, you then set the web site/application to that specific IP address if you want that site to have it's own IP.

If you want to share an IP with multiple sites, you can do so with `host headers` in IIS.

[image: IIS site binding]

Hth...